# App screen size is too small for the ios simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

Here is a screen shot of an ipad 10.5 inch running my app which takes up around 50% of the screen real estate. How do I force the app to use 100% of the screen real estate? (I am using xcode 10) [image]

Comment: why u just don't drag your simulator and make it bigger ?

Comment: Dragging the simulator makes no difference the actual app dimensions stay at 50% the size of the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify it in Xcode. If you don't the ipad is getting a scaled up version of ui for iPhone 4. Open Xcode and specify it "General" project settings.

Comment: Can you be more specific please??

Answer (score 1):

May be your IOS setting preference is wrong. You are opening your application on ipad but XCode rendering your application as iPhone app.

- Go to general setting and select "iPad" in Deployment Info section.
- Go to Build Setting and select "iPad" in Targeted Device Families under Deployment section.
- Restart your project.